# How do I configure DataStudio filter control to have a default selection of null?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a DataStudio chart of type table and a filter control both connected to the same datasource. The filter control references a dimension that can contain empty values. When applying a filter (by manual selection), the empty values appear as `null` and the table is filtered as expected.

My goal is to apply a *default selection* to the filter control so that empty values are **included** by default. The filter control allows me to provide a comma separated list for the *default selection*, however:

- If I use the text `null`, it is treated as the text literal `null`. The same is true for `(null)` which is treated as the text literal `(null)`.
- If I use a leading comma (`,filter`), or a trailing comma (`filter,`), it is treated as `filter` and `""` which doesn't match `null`.

The question is, how do I get a filter control's default selection to match results where the value is null/doesn't exist (by default)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit (Apr 2022): As pointed out by @simplycoding below, this is now available by selecting a filter - Data - Control Field - Default selection.

Original Answer:
This is currently not possible (Dec 2019). A workaround could be to create a calculated field where null values from the original column are replaced with a predefined value. Then filter based on the new column.

Comment: I think think does not answer the question. The question is: What syntax do you use to default to `null` values in the default selection of a filter control? The question is not: how do you use a default selection